# How do I discover the correct Java 11 module names for my GeoTools project?

Tags: java, java-11, java-module, geotools

I am trying to convert my application to use Java 11 and the java module system, but am having difficulty discovering which "requires" statements to add to my module-info.java. I am currently getting the error `"The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.locationtech.jts.geom.Envelope. Fix the build path then try building this project"`.

I have searched through https://github.com/geotools/geotools, but I cannot find any hints regarding which modules expose which packages. For example there is a module "org.geotools.tile_client", but searching that in the repository gets zero hits (so I assume the geotools modules are not handled via config files?).

The geotools Javadoc is unfortunately also not helpful, as geotools is not yet using named modules.

https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/java11.html mentioned using the same requires as the ones declared in my POM, but for my project requireing (gt-shapefile, gt-swing, gt-tile-client, gt-epsg-hsql, gt-grid) this resulted in the error:

`The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem. Fix the build path then try building this project`

Through digging down through the maven dependencies, I found a few more which I now explicitely require too. This brought me past a few more errors.

```
requires org.geotools.opengis;
requires org.geotools.referencing;
requires org.geotools.coverage;
requires org.geotools.main;
requires org.geotools.render;
requires org.geotools.epsg_hsql;
requires org.geotools.shapefile;
requires org.geotools.grid;
requires org.geotools.tile_client;
requires org.geotools.swing;
requires org.geotools.http;
```

However, I did find a module which doesnt seem to want to work (gt-cql, dependency of gt-render). requires org.geotools.cql cannot be resolved.

So, as asked at the top, how do I discover the correct Java 11 module names for my GeoTools project? And is there a specific hint as to which module I should require in order to get rid of the org.locationtech.jts.geom.Envelope problem?

Answer (score 2):

Took a while to come to this, but I have come to the following solution thanks to the jar --describe-module command from  [Is it possible to mix Java 8 and Java 9 source code in the same project without using compiler flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359025/is-it-possible-to-mix-java-8-and-java-9-source-code-in-the-same-project-without).

1. Using mvn dependency:copy-dependencies copies all .jar files to target/dependency.
2. In target/dependency, create a file "module-report.cmd" with the following content.:

   > module-report.txt (
   for %%f in (%~dp0*.jar) do (
   jar --file=%%f --describe-module
   )
   )

Its just running the "jar --file=... --describe-module" command on every jar file, outputting it to module-report.txt.

3. Run module-report.cmd to generate module-report.txt

The contents of the text file contain all of the module information, including contained packages, requires declarations, everything.

Using that report I could then simply search for the packages I couldn't access and easily get the name of the module they were contained in.